# Stateful Web Services

Tags: web-services, stateful

I'm building a java/spring application, and i may need to incorporate a stateful web service call.
Any opinions if i should totally run away from a stateful services call, or it can be done and is enterprise ready?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stateful web services are a pain to maintain.  The mechanism I have seen for them is to have the first call return an id (basically a transaction id) that is used in subsequent calls.  A problem with that is that the web service isn't really stateful so it has to load all the information that it needs from some other data store for each call.

Answer (score 7):

Statefulness runs counter to the basic architecture of HTTP (ask Roy Fielding), and reduces scalability.